# How do I type system of equations in the same line with text in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

I want my document like this

[image]

(system of equations in the same line with text) not like this

[image]

Can anyone help me please? Here is my code for the second picture:

```
\hspace{2ex} Theo hệ thức Viète, ta có:
    $$\begin{cases}  
        x_1 + x_2 = 2(m-1)\\ 
        x_1 x_2 = -3-m
    \end{cases} $$
```

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of typesetting mathematical equations in LaTeX, namely *text style* and *display style*. You are trying to write an in-line equation which is text style but the syntax `$$<some equation>$$` is used for *display style*. The syntax for *text style* is `$<some equation>$`. So your code should be

```latex
\hspace{2ex} Theo hệ thức Viète, ta có:
    $\begin{cases}  
        x_1 + x_2 = 2(m-1)\\ 
        x_1 x_2 = -3-m
    \end{cases}$
```

[MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \hspace{2ex} Theo hệ thức Viète, ta có:
    $\begin{cases}  
        x_1 + x_2 = 2(m-1)\\ 
        x_1 x_2 = -3-m
    \end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

*Note:* You should use `\[<some equation>\]` instead of `$$<some equation>$$` for *display style*. You may find the reason [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).